# Playing Multiple Audio Files Simultaneously

Tags: android, audio, mp3, media

I want to play multiple audio files simultaneously in sync. I want to load the files using their URI (source will be either a Ringtone, file on the SDcard, or a file in a specific folder). I want to be able to put a delay on the files and adjust the play rate. I have looked into SoundPool and MediaPlayer, but I am unsure of which one is best. MediaPlayer seems like the right path, but I don't know the best method to store and play the different players.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been told that MediaPlayer is easier to work with if you don't have a lot of files, and SoundPool is for more complicated things like if you want to have sounds for a game. I don't think you can put delays and adjust the play rate if you use the MediaPlayer API though, it doesn't seem like there's that function: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html